# Can alerts be added to a Grafana Panel on a dashboard using API?

Tags: grafana, grafana-api

There is a Grafana dashboard with a panel inside it. Is it possible to add (or define) an API?

Answer (score 0):

To create new alerts or modify them you need to update the dashboard json that contains the alerts. Use [dashboard API](http://docs.grafana.org/http_api/dashboard/) and edit particular panel alert section. You need to define an alert there. For example:

```
  "alert": {
    "conditions": [
      {
        "type": "query",
        "query": {
          "params": [
            "A",
            "5m",
            "now"
          ]
        },
        "reducer": {
          "type": "avg",
          "params": []
        },
        "evaluator": {
          "type": "gt",
          "params": [
            null
          ]
        },
        "operator": {
          "type": "and"
        }
      }
    ],
```